# How to know if the key and certificate are using?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl

I'm working on the Express API Javascript code in a way that uses the self-signed SSL certificate.

I created a self-signed SSL certificate using: https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015960428-How-to-Generate-a-Self-Signed-Certificate-and-Private-Key-using-OpenSSL

Then, I put the `privateKey.key`, `certificate.crt`, and `server.js` in the same folder.

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const port = 443;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("IT'S WORKING!");
});

require("http")
  .createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync("privateKey.key"),
      cert: fs.readFileSync("certificate.crt"),
    },
    app
  )
  .listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`);
  });
```

I ran nodemon server.js in terminal and below is the output:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Listening on port 443!
```

I tested it in the browser by `localhost:443`. Then the response `IT'S WORKING` showed up.

My question is Am I doing correctly to the Express API Javascript code with the self-signed SSL certificate? How to know exactly the self-signed SSL certificate is being used?

Thank you so much

Comment: Click the little lock icon in your browser's address bar.

Comment: The info icon is there instead of lock icon. When I click on the info icon, I see 'your connection to the site is not secure'

Comment: Oh you're serving over HTTP instead of HTTP/S.

Comment: I just fixed it. The secure icon showed up

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the client's and server's handshake data. Your SSL certificate should be in one of the server's responses data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).